# trying to show more than 50 results corresponding to single topic id using freebase in android

Tags: youtube-api

I want to get more than 50 youtube video results corresponding to topic id ........so i am trying to get next page token.......
in youtube api v3 in android
and url used is....
**https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet&order=relevancee&topicId="+topicId+"&q="+videoId+"&key="**

but the error giving is......

```
 "error": {

   "errors": [

    {
     "domain": "youtube.parameter",

     "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",

     "message": "No filter selected.",

    "locationType": "parameter",


    "location": ""

    }

   ],
   "code": 400,

   "message": "No filter selected."

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set type = video

Whenever you are using a video specific filter you have to filter type as well. As search is unified, otherwise it normally returns playlist, channel and videos as a result.

You can always try your queries in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/) before implementing.